Intermittent Message Loss in ROS2 Publisher-Subscriber Setup for Multiple Robots
I am working with a ROS2 setup that includes a PathPublisher node and a ControlNode for managing multiple robots. While my implementation is generally functional, I am experiencing intermittent message loss, where the ControlNode sometimes receives path messages for some robots but misses them for others.
Code Overview
PathPublisher Node:
PathPublisher::PathPublisher() : Node("path_publisher") {
  this->declare_parameter<int>("num_robots", 1);
  this->declare_parameter<std::vector<double>>("initial_positions", {0.0, 0.0, 0.0});
  this->declare_parameter<std::string>("table_name", "example.tbl");

  this->get_parameter("num_robots", num_robots);
  this->get_parameter("table_name", table_name);

  std::vector<double> long_positions;
  const int num_pos = 3;

  this->get_parameter("initial_positions", long_positions);
  initial_positions.resize(num_robots);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_robots; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num_pos; j++) {
      initial_positions[i].push_back(long_positions[num_pos * i + j]);
    }
  }

  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Path publisher node active!");

  // QoS Profile
  rclcpp::QoS qos_profile(50);
  qos_profile.reliability(rclcpp::ReliabilityPolicy::Reliable);
  qos_profile.durability(rclcpp::DurabilityPolicy::TransientLocal);

  for (int i = 0; i < num_robots; i++) {
    path_publishers_.push_back(this->create_publisher<nav_msgs::msg::Path>(
        "/robot" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "/path", qos_profile));
  }

  RunEngine();
}

ControlNode:
ControlNode::ControlNode() : Node("bang_ctrl") {
  this->declare_parameter<std::string>("robot_name", "default_robot");
  robot_name = this->get_parameter("robot_name").as_string();
  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "robot_name: %s", robot_name.c_str());

  // QoS Profile
  rclcpp::QoS qos_profile(10);
  qos_profile.reliability(rclcpp::ReliabilityPolicy::Reliable);
  qos_profile.durability(rclcpp::DurabilityPolicy::TransientLocal);

  // Subscriptions and publishers
  odom_subscriber = this->create_subscription<nav_msgs::msg::Odometry>(
      "/" + robot_name + "/odom", 10,
      std::bind(&ControlNode::OdomCallback, this, _1));

  vel_publisher = this->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>(
      "/" + robot_name + "/cmd_vel", 10);

  path_subscriber = this->create_subscription<nav_msgs::msg::Path>(
      "/" + robot_name + "/path", qos_profile,
      std::bind(&ControlNode::PathCallback, this, _1));
}

void ControlNode::PathCallback(const nav_msgs::msg::Path::SharedPtr msg) {
  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Received path with %zu poses", msg->poses.size());

  std::thread([this, msg]() {
    // Processing logic...
  }).detach();
}

Observations
I am using QoS settings to ensure message reliability and transient local durability.
The publishers seem to be correctly instantiated for each robot.
The message loss is inconsistent, making troubleshooting challenging.
Request for Assistance
Has anyone encountered similar issues or have suggestions on what to investigate? Are there specific aspects of the QoS settings, threading model, or other potential problems I should consider?
Thank you for your help!

I anyone ever face this kind of problem try to use a function get_subscription_count() make a check on your number of robots if the number of robots is not reached keep looping like:
for(int i = 0; i < num_robots; i++) {
    int num = path_publishers_[i]->get_subscription_count();
    if(num == 0) {
      --i;
      continue;
    }
  }

Purpose of get_subscription_count():
Monitoring Subscriptions: It allows developers to monitor how many subscriptions are currently active. This can be useful for debugging or understanding the node's behavior.
Resource Management: Knowing the number of active subscriptions can help in managing system resources more effectively. If a node has too many subscriptions, it may require more processing power and memory.
Dynamic Behavior: In applications where subscriptions might be added or removed dynamically, this method can help in adapting the node's functionality based on the current state of subscriptions.
Feedback Loop: It can be part of a feedback mechanism in complex systems, where nodes may need to adjust their operations based on how many other nodes are communicating with them.
